# Can I drive the Animal Population of Skyrim into Extinction?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Are all or certain animal populations endangered by the Dragonborn? Can I, by my hunting, drive the whole population of wolves, mammoths, and giants into extinction? Or will the game repopulate the world again? If so, is there a pattern?

Comment: For regular animals: [Is there a finite amount of foxes/wolves/horkers, etc.?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37574/is-there-a-finite-amount-of-foxes-wolves-horkers-etc/). Don't know about giants and mammoths, though.

Comment: Yes, if you kill enough of any animal type, PETA activists appear. They're easy to kill but, being naked, they don't have any loot :(

Comment: That must be how I obtain human hearts for alchemy.

Comment: Naked? They're wearing human suits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just fast traveled to

> Secunda's Kiss

to check out whether giants respawn. I killed the giants there on my first trip from Riverwood to Whiterun by abusing the pathing.

The giants were back. They do respawn.

SevenSidedDie points to the answer for animals in his comment: yes, they also respawn.

I also recently revisited

> Shearpoint

and the dragon there had respawned, so even the static dragons respawn.

Comment: Note that if you kill the same dragon multiple times, you can only absorb its soul the first time.

Answer (score -1):

I have killed every Mammoth and Giant at the Giant camp sites. When fast traveling back to the camp sites later, I have found that although the Giants *do* re-spawn, the Mammoths **do not**.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. I'm pretty sure I've killed mammoths multiple times. Pretty much anything without a unique name respawns.

Answer (score -2):

The Giants and Mammoths can become extinct if you check the elder scrolls wiki it says for ''the cursed tribe mission'' ''If every giant camp has already been cleared before completing this quest, the giants will be extinct, as will the mammoths.''

Comment: The Elder Scrolls Wiki is notoriously unreliable. Use the [Unofficial Elder Scrolls Pages](http://www.uesp.net) instead.